# How to use another app to find a file?

Tags: android, file

I'm trying to get my app to open another app, a file manager, to select a file and return it's path to my app. For example if I were to go to my phone's web broswer and attempt to upload something to the web, it'd ask what app I want to use to select the file. Choosing the file manager I would then search for the file, select it and then send it back to the web browser for the upload. How would I do this in my app, I've looked at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html but it hasn't helped me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage

Comment: @CommonsWare This allows me to pick a file but it doesn't let me interact with the file manager.

Comment: @CommonsWare Nvm, I figured that bit out.

Comment: Android does not have a file manager, other than to the extent you consider the one that you get from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+.

Comment: By file manager I meant one I had downloaded.

Comment: Ask the developer of that file manager what API it supports.